# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error when preforming a JSONP call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to get this call going for some time now and can't seem to figure out what is causing the issue..

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#button").on('click', function(){
  console.log("Button has been clicked!");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "http://api.bulkwhoisapi.com/whoisAPI.php?domain=yoursite.com&token=7d3f08b98ab9f69ae15060a5b58ef1ee",
    success: function(whoIs){
      console.log(whoIs);
    }
  })
})

})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: That page has JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124651/cross-domain-ajax-called-with-jsonp-returns-plain-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONP request returning error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046008/jsonp-request-returning-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)